# Mysql Create Database with special characters in the name

Tags: mysql, special-characters

I want to create a database which name will have special characters in it. for example,
(., - , _, @, #, $, %, &, *)

can anyone provide any output on this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I would strongly recommend that you do not create databases with such names. But if you absolutely must, here are the [restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html):

- No identifier can contain ASCII NUL (0x00) or a byte with a value of 255.
- Database, table, and column names should not end with space characters.
- Database and table names cannot contain “/”, “\”, “.”, or characters that are not allowed in file names.

To create a database, you can do the following:

```
mysql> create database `really@strange*database$name`;
```

Comment: i want to create it dynamically, can i do that? for example - i want to give a database name to a variable 
set @a = name.surname;

create database @a;

Comment: Thanks a lot Andre. It was a great help as i was needing to it, though it is not advisable. Thanks :)

Comment: How come some servers allow me to use \ in table names?

Comment: Why do you say these ` “/”, “\”, “.”` are not allowed? **create database backtick:backtick** works.. only the space at the end is an issue. In fact, mysql doesn't create a physical file `:` on disk, it changes the name appropriately.

Comment: @nawfal, I was quoting that from the documentation. If you follow the 'restrictions' link, you will see it listed there. I am not sure why it is mentioned in the documentation if you can in fact create such tables.

Comment: @AndreMiller, How do you escape the backticks? If we would like to have a backtick as the database name.

Comment: @Pacerier You can escape backticks in a MySQL identifier by doubling them. E.g., `myweird\`\`name`. If the name is dynamic, you also may want to strip out null characters, as they are disallowed, and software often doesn't handle them properly.

Comment: @ChrisMiddleton, Wow, Nice, we can actually do `create database````;`. Is there any way to do that for tables as well?

Comment: @Pacerier That method applies to all mysql identifiers - dbs, tables, columns, and indexes - though I wouldn't advise doing it. Ex: `ALTER TABLE \`test\`\`\`.\`test\`\`\` ADD UNIQUE \`test\`\`\` ( \`test\`\`\` ) ` (That's an index created on a column in a table in a database, where all of the former are named `test\``.)

Comment: This answer has been around a long time, but it's not correct. I referred to this answer before doing some work, and in my work I found that '-' hyphen characters are not allowed in database names. `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS foo-bar;` gives `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;` but then `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS foo_bar;` works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Simple: Don't.

You *can* escape exotic table names using the backtick in mysql, but I don't know if you can use *anything* inside the backticks. It will give great amounts of pain during the rest of your software life cycle.

I would rather recommend creating another table to hold that exotic names.

```
-- Example:
CREATE TABLE _DatabaseMetadata (
    databaseName VARCHAR(255),
    exoticName VARCHAR(255)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

- Don't. I strongly recommend to keep all identifiers consisting of A-Z,a-z,0-9 and _ characters. You can store Your "exotic" name in a column or comment.

Long answer:

- You can name your columns, tables, keys, foreign keys, views, even databases using exotic characters but chances are You're gonna regret it in the future.
- If You insist in doing that, You gonna need quoting Your identifiers in backticks (`).
- In case Your identifier has to contain another ` inside, You can escape it stating it twice (e.g. exotic`name --> `exotic``name`)
- For the things not to be so simple, if You use exotic (or even non-conventional) characters in the name of Your database (including a simple space), those characters (to my knowledge, everything except a-z,A-Z,0-9 and _) get escaped into 4-digit hexadecimal quadruplets escaped by @, e.g. `my database` becomes my@0020database. This form is used as a name of a directories/files in which Your databases/tables are stored, and e.g. items in information_schema.INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN, moreover may very well be OS-dependent (meaning, theoretically, You might want to run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version_compile_os'` to adapt to it). You see - with exotic names it all gets much, much more complicated and in the end it's not really worth it.

Comment: This may no longer be an issue for newer (MySQL 8+) installations, but I would additionally not recommend using exotic characters in comments, as MySQL has historically had tons of issues enforcing and converting comment encoding, to the point where you couldn't upgrade your MySQL server because of it.